# "Strange" isomorphism $\mathbb C^*/C_n\simeq \mathbb C^*$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Prove the "strange" isomorphism: $\mathbb C^*/C_n\simeq \mathbb C^*$.

My solution: 
The map  $f:x\mapsto x^n$ is homomorphism since $f(x)f(y)=x^n y^n=(xy)^n=f(xy)$,
$\mathrm{ker}\,f=C_n$, $\mathrm{im}\,f=\mathbb C^*$. Therefore, by the homomorphism theorem: $\mathbb C^*/C_n\simeq \mathbb C^*$.

Here $C_n$ is the root of unity.
Could someone prove it and correct if it's needed.

Comment: Your solution seems pretty good to me.

Comment: Depending on your reader, you might want to explain a bit more why the image if all of $\mathbb C^*$, e.g., by saying that any $re^{i \theta}$ in the codomain has the number $\sqrt[n]{r}e^{i\theta/n}$ as a preimage, but yes it looks good.

Comment: @AlexProvost : Do you know why it's called as a "strange" isomorphism in the book?

Comment: @Metso Because, morally, the "equation" $A/B = A$ has no right to hold when $A$ and $B$ are nontrivial, because the left hand side should be "smaller" than the right hand side. (If they were real numbers, "nontrivial" would mean $A \neq 0$ and $B \neq 1$; as groups, it means that $A$ and $B$ are not trivial groups.) Of course, here it works because we are not working with the strict notion of "equality" but rather the more lenient condition of "isomorphism".

Comment: The idea being that subdividing the punctured complex plane into $n$ equal parts and working only with one slice, multiplicatively, yields as much information as working with the whole punctured plane – the isomorphism "stretches" the slice into the whole punctured plane bijectively while also preserving the group structure.

Comment: The key here is that $\mathbb{C}^*$ is infinite, so we can divide it by $n$ and be left with something just as big (in fact isomorphic as a group).